# there's a way who can help me to give all the items font-family and font-size joomla?

Tags: html, fonts, joomla2.5, wysiwyg

I am a begginer to joomla and I thank you in advance for your help. 
I have 400 items in the extension k2 of which I have to define the font-family and font-size, this could make it article by article through the wysiwyg do this but it would be boring and I would lose a lot of time ... there's a way who can help me to give all the items font-family and font-size?

Comment: You could set these values to your css file

Comment: could you tell me which path brings me to the css file that I need to change? thank you for your answer

Comment: It would be in your template folder: templates/your_template/css/css_file.css / your_template = your template name / css_file = the template css file name

Comment: You could try: div#k2Container .itemIntroText, div#k2Container .itemFullText { font-size: 14px; font-family: arial; }

Comment: I find this file in my phpMyAdmin, Joomla or finder?'m sorry I'm really a beginner and are highly motivated to learn and succeed

Comment: You have to connect with ftp and add the css values to your template css file

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selectors to set defaults and overrides, for example:

```
* { font-family: serif; font-size: larger; }
```

as the first statement of the CSS file will set the default:

```
div div { font-family: sans-serif; font-size: initial; }
```

will override that for nested div elements.

**References**

- [CSS2: Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)